# How to add media attachments for the custom post type in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, gallery, media

I need to implement functionality in the admin Panel in such a way that I can add images for the gallery of particular custom post type also I would be able to view/edit the all the images uploaded from the admin panel.

P.S I want to develop this functionality in the theme without using any plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the custom field into which you can call the attachments without any plugin. Please refer to the below code:

```php
add_action('admin_init', 'show_custom_post_images');

function show_custom_post_images() {
  add_meta_box(
    'Pictures ',
    __('Images attached to post ', 'domain'),
    'post_image',
    'post_type',
    'normal',
    'default'
  );
}

function post_image() {
  global $post;
  $arguments = array(
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => null,
    'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id() ,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  $post_attachments = get_posts($arguments);
  foreach ($post_attachments as $attachment) {
    $preview = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
      $attachment->ID, 'wpestate_slider_thumb'
    );
    echo '<img src="' . $preview[0] . '">';
  }
}
```

This will show all the images attached to the post in a custom field below.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look as below:

- First of all, install the ACF plugin and create a repeater field if you want to add more than 1 image to a post else you no need repeater field.

If you want to display all post iamges as gallery on fronend from ACF repeater field, Plesae have a look as below:

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ): ?>
 <ul class="slides">
   <?php
     while( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ): the_row();
     $image = get_sub_field('image');
   ?>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
      </li>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to show the image without repeater field, Please have a look below:

```
<?php
  $image = get_field('instructor-image');
  if( !empty($image) ):
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to implement this without use of any plugins into this .

Comment: Okay, @Pratikb.Simform I will update my answer with custom functionality instead of ACF and let you know. Thanks